# sbt compile fails with bad option: '-Ywarn-macros:after'

Tags: scala, sbt, compiler-flags, circe, scalac

With a build.sbt file like:

```
ThisBuild / organization := "com.company"
ThisBuild / version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

Global / concurrentRestrictions += Tags.limit(Tags.Test, 1)

Global / scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Ypartial-unification",
                               "-unchecked",
                               "-Xfatal-warnings",
                               "-Ywarn-dead-code",
                               "-Ywarn-inaccessible",
                               "-Ywarn-unused",
                               "-Ywarn-unused-import",
                               "-Ywarn-macros:after")
```

I get `[error] bad option: '-Ywarn-macros:none'` after running `sbt clean compile`

Without `-Ywarn-macros:after`, the unused import warning raises spurious warnings in files using Circe macros, for example: `import io.circe.{ Decoder, Encoder }`.

Comment: Do you have an example where you get spurious warnings with circe?

Comment: In trying to construct a small example of -Ywarn-unused-import creating a spurious warning when using Circe, I wasn't seeing any such warnings. And now those warnings also are not appearing in my actual project. I suppose sometimes a good night's sleep is the best debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Ywarn-macros` wasn't added until Scala 2.12, so the error is expected.

Can you upgrade to Scala 2.12? If you are stuck on 2.11, perhaps you will need to live without `-Ywarn-unused-import`. (Unused warnings in general have greatly improved as the 2.12.x series has progressed, thanks to tireless work on it by Som Snytt.)

You might be able to confine the Circe-using code to a subproject, and then disable unused warnings in that subproject only, in order to leave them enabled in the rest of your codebase.

Another possibility is to try https://github.com/ghik/silencer.